# MySQL - Select specific rows in a table which are related to another table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables as follows

**Table 1**

```
Userid            Name        Gender         Country
===================================================
u001              Name 1      Female           IN
u002              Name 2      Male             US
u003              Name 3      Male             IN
u004              Name 4      Female           UK
u005              Name 5      Female           US
```

**Table 2**

```
Userid               UserRole                    Status
=======================================================
u001                   r001                         1
u002                   r002                         1
u003                   r002                         1
u004                   r002                         1
u005                   r003                         1
```

I want to select all the rows in Table 1 (using `join` is optional) which are ***Females*** and have **`userRole`** as `'r002'`.

I am unable to find a suitable syntax to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM `table_1` WHERE `Gender` = 'Female' and `Userid` in (SELECT `Userid` FROM `table_2` where `UserRole` = 'r002')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM `table_1` t1
INNER JOIN `table_2` t2 ON (t1.Userid = t2.Userid AND t2.UserRole = 'r002')
WHERE 
    t1.Gender = 'Female'
```

Comment: Please tell me what `join` (inner join, equi join etc.) did you use ?